# BATCH SCRIPT - Automatizando o login em sites

Tags: script, batch, automatização

Tenho o objetivo de criar um arquivo .bat que automatize o meu login num determinado site.

Eu consigo abrir o site com o .bat através do comando start chrome.exe "meusite.com", e gostaria de saber como criar um script que pressione duas vezes a tecla <kbd>TAB</kbd> e uma vez a tecla <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

Exemplo de como eu imagino que seja:

```
start chrome.exe "http://www.meusite.com"
teclado_automatico "{Alt}"
teclado_automatico "{Alt}"
teclado_automatico "{Enter}"
```

Comment: Você pode tentar uma abordagem diferente com powershell, ao invés de abrir o navegador, faria uma requisição e passaria no corpo(post) dela o login e senha.

Comment: obrigado pela dica @rray

Comment: Depois fazer login no site, vc precisa fazer o que?

Comment: somente apresentar a tela em fullscreen, será apenas para exibição

Answer (score 3):

Um exemplo em  VBS, com internet explorer que vc pode adaptar :

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.AppActivate "Internet Explorer"
Wscript.Sleep 1500
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
Wscript.Sleep 1500
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
Wscript.Sleep 1500
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
Wscript.Sleep 1500
```

Answer (score 3):

Uma outra alternativa seria utilizar ferramentas como o [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) ou [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) que são linguagens de automação para o sistema Windows e possuem vários recursos para simular uma interação de usuário.

Segue exemplo utilizando o **AutoIt**:

```
#include <IE.au3>
' Abre o Internet Explorer
Local $oIE = _IECreate("www.meusite.com", 1)

' Aguarda o carregamento da página
_IELoadWait($oIE)

' Captura os elementos pelo id
Local $oUsuario = _IEGetObjById($oIE, "usuario")
Local $oSenha = _IEGetObjById($oIE, "senha")
Local $oBotao = _IEGetObjById($oIE, "btn")

' Define os valores
$oUsuario.value = "foo"
$oSenha.value = "bar"

' Simula um clique
_IEAction($oBotao, "click")
```

Answer (score 1):

Creio que a solução mais adequada para o seu problema de automação de tarefas relativas a um browser é utilizar ferramentas feitas exatamente pra isso. Uma das mais conhecidas é a iMacros. Tem plugin para o Chrome e Firefox.

O iMacros possui, inclusive, uma linguagem de programação própria, podendo utilizar também Javascript para as automações. Utilizei na empresa que trabalho para facilitar a entrada de NFe (Notas Fiscais Eletrônicas), enquanto a integração com o ERP (via web service), não havia sido feita.

Site: http://imacros.net/overview